# ios 5.1 memory leak in libsystem_c.dylib strdup

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am creating a application something like as eBook. I am using UIScrollView to display page. When i am moving one page to another or zoom on the page, i am getting memory leak in lib system_c.dylib strdup. I am getting this error frequently. When i am seeing more than 100 pages, then my application is crashed. Anywork around, to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly a bug in iOS 5.1. [Read more.](https://devforums.apple.com/message/630695#630695)

Comment: I guess that you have only one way use another sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely for libsystem_c.dylib strdup to have a leak. What is probably happening is that the memory was allocated in ibsystem_c.dylib strdup but your code, directly or indirectly, is responsible of freeing that memory and it is not doing so.

Use the Leaks instrument to check out the stack at the moment the memory was allocated. There is probably some code of yours in the stack that making a call that is allocating that memory.